# Monodevelop crashes on Windows using nunit test due to | character

Tags: c#, crash, nunit, monodevelop

I'm using `Monodevelop 2.8.6.5` and trying to run unit tests constantly returns an internal error:

```
`ArgumentException`: Illegal characters in path
at System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(string)
at ...
at ...
at MonoDevelop.NUnit.XmlResultsStore.GetRootRecord(string configuration...)
```

Basically the problem is that `MonoDevelop.NUnit.XmlResultsStore.GetRootRecord` is passing `"Debug|x86"` as the configuration, which it is then trying to create a path or folder for, and gets an exception because | is illegal.  I can create a configuration that doesn't have the |, but MonoDevelop gets horribly confused.  Because it assumes that means "Any Platform", so I can't make an `x86 build.`  That means I can't run the program, but I can `Unit Test` it.

My current options are text hacking the `.sln` and `.csproj` files until both work or just having two solution configurations, I suppose.

More confoundingly I have yet to see a single question about this online, which seems like a guaranteed issue.

Anyone know what to do?  If there's a solution - `"file a bug report"` is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

That's definitely a bug, and your diagnosis of the issue looks correct. Please file it at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com.

Note that a solution configuration is a map to a set of projects to include in the build and their configurations to use. The name of the solution configuration doesn't have to match the project configuration. This means you may be able to work around it the bug by having the Debug|x86 solution configuration use the Debug|AnyCPU configuration of the unit test project.

There probably isn't anything wrong with this, because you probably don't actually need the platform set to x86 anyway. The explanation is rather complicated, but I'll give it a shot.

New desktop executable projects in MonoDevelop have "Debug|x86" and "Release|x86" configurations, for compatibility with Visual Studio. Having "x86" as the platform component of the configuration *name* doesn't actually have any direct effect on the compilation or execution of the binaries, but these particular configurations also set the C# compiler options' platform value to "x86", which sets a flag in the compiled binary. For executables, this flag means that when Windows x64 executes the binary, it uses the x86 .NET runtime instead of the default x64 runtime. For libraries, it means that the x64 .NET runtime will refuse to load the library. The Mono runtime ignores the flag completely.

AFAIK, by making executable projects target x86 by default, MS made it so that developers wouldn't have problems problems P/Invoking libraries that only existed on 32-bit Windows. Since most programs don't need to run in x64 mode, this was presumably worth the trade-off.

An x86 process can load AnyCPU libraries just fine, so new library projects always have the AnyCPU configuration name, and don't set the compiler flag. VS generally creates "Mixed" solution configurations that map to the x86 executable project configurations and the AnyCPU library project configurations.

Unfortunately, MonoDevelop is overzealous about creating matching-named configurations in all proejcts, even when they aren't needed or don't make sense. Chances are that MD created x86-named configurations for your library projects, including the NUnit test project. They wouldn't have the x86 compiler flag set, and you wouldn't need it anyway, so you could delete them and map all the solution configurations to the AnyCPU library configurations.

Note also that when MD runs the NUnit tests, it loads the test library using its own remote host process executable, which is marked as x86. So the tests will run in x86 anyway, even on 64-bit Windows.